# jquery how can i keep sub menu closed until main menu is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, submenu, slidingmenu

Here is the current code: sub menu is opening automatically, would like it to stay closed until the main menu is clicked-

http://jsbin.com/odegik/50/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">                      </script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>DEMO</title>
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>



</style>
</head>
<body>
```

here is the code: jquery is kicking my butt :)

```
 <nav class="menu-desktop">
  <ul class="main-menu">
        <li data-ref="Top1"><a href="/index.php" >Main Link1</a></li>
        </ul>
  <ul class="Top1" >
        <li><a href="#" >sub link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#1">sub name2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">sub name3</a></li>
        <li><a href="$">sub name4</a></li>   
  </ul>

<ul class="main-menu">
<li data-ref="Top2"><a href="#" >Main Link2</a></li>
        </ul>
  <ul class="Top2" >
        <li><a href="#" >2sub link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#1">sub name22</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">sub name23</a></li>
        <li><a href="$">sub name24</a></li>   
  </ul>

<ul class="main-menu">
<li data-ref="Top3"><a href="#" >Main Link3</a></li>
        </ul>
  <ul class="Top3" >
        <li><a href="#" >3sub link</a></li>
        <li><a href="/_3Testingonly.php">sub name32</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">sub name33</a></li>
        <li><a href="$">sub name34</a></li>   
  </ul>  
</nav>  

</body>
</html>
```

jquery is kicking my butt :)

```
var submenu;

$('.main-menu li').click(function(){
var elems = $('.menu-desktop ul:not(.main-menu)').length;
var $refClass = $('.' + $(this).attr('data-ref'));
var visible = $refClass.is(':visible');

$('.menu-desktop ul:not(.main-menu)').slideUp(100, function() {

    if (elems == 1) {
        if (!visible) $refClass.slideDown('fast');
    }

    elems--;
});

if (visible) $('#breadcrumbs-pc').animate({'margin-top':'0rem'}, 100);
else $('#breadcrumbs-pc').animate({'margin-top':'5rem'}, 100);
});
```

Comment: is there are reason for not nesting the menus? What I mean is creating a tree with ul li ul all in one main menu?

Comment: Hi Ricardo, sorry I am a newbie and don't follow your question. you can post an example of what you are referring to. Thank You :)

Comment: You should print and study [these selector guides](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp). Keep hitting Next Chapter for 4 or 5 screens. Memorize the selectors, especially. A few hours work over a week or two and you'll be a jQuery master.

Comment: I asked because if you do it like that you can hide all the children and work with the selectors in a more organized way. You still can do it, but it will be a matter of better practices. If I have some time later I'll create an example.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, yeah that would be great. i'll keep an eye out for that. on a side note, can you tell me if the jquery code has to be inside the <body> in order to work correctly? are there any other locations that is preferred? thank you :)

Comment: It doesn't need to be in the body. It can be at the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS to hide it initially:

```
.main-menu + ul { display:none; }
```

Comment: ok, making progress. page can be viewed on my website: http://www.ceramictilepro.com/_5testingonly.php   also here http://jsbin.com/idirEpU/1/edit i did notice that my page loads funky and bounces around since the jquery has been included. also was looking to see if the sub menu can stay open AFTER a link is clicked so the person browsing knows where they are. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I saw your final work. Good job. A little late and I know you don't need it, but as promised here what I meant in my comments. [Here's the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardonunez/jZfKX/).

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Element 1</li>
        <li>Element 2</li>
        <li>Element 3</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Services</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Element 4</li>
        <li>Element 5</li>
        <li>Element 6</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('li').click(function(){
        $('ul.menu ul').slideUp('fast'); // hides all the submenu that are open
            var submenu = $(this).next('ul');
        if ( $(this).next('ul').is(':visible') ) {
            submenu.slideUp('fast'); // if is already open, it will hide it. if you don't care about one being always open, delete this if statement and keep the last line slideToggle.
        } else {
            submenu.slideToggle('fast'); // toggles within open and close.
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
ul.menu { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 200px; font-family: arial;}
ul.menu ul { display: none; }
ul.menu li { list-style: none; border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; padding: 10px; }
ul.menu ul { padding: 0; background: #EEEEEE  }
```

Comment: hey thanks ricardo :) is there a reason why you have two ul.menu ul with different code? just curious. newbie here :) thanks again!

Comment: hey ricardo, check out my website http://www.ceramictilepro.com/How-To-Clean-Grout.php i have been working on it all weekend and was able to color the current page with red buttons. still trying to figure out how to keep that accordian vertical menu open when the sub menu link has been clicked (which opens another page). i have realised that the jquery is just a bit too much at this point to tackle. i would actually pay someone to get it working lol. thanks again buddy :)

Comment: You may want to do that in PHP. Add a class to the open/selected/current menu that shows it. You don't want jQuery to do all the work rendering your website, it will slow it down.

Comment: ok great! i will start reading up on PHP stuff. thank you :) actually can't believe i have my website looking the way it does by not knowing anything. thanks to google and a lot of trial and error stuff.